# Ubuntu 20.04 somehow starting 2 users?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gdm, gnome-session, remote-x-session

I have Ubuntu 20.04. I was trying to setup chrome remote desktop and then after I set it up and try to connect I had to choose session it was black screen and when I restarted my computer I prompted password again and again.

How can i disable the gdm-x-session gnome-session from logging in everytime i restart?

here is the output of `$ w`

```
 23:12:48 up 47 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.14, 0.82, 0.65
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
ahmetkca :1       :1               22:26   ?xdm?   9:32   0.00s /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu /usr/bin/g
ahmetkca pts/0    :1               23:12    0.00s  0.40s  0.00s w
```

i installed `lxde` because i couldn't connect chrome remote desktop on default ubuntu session

I acutally don't know the root cause of the user logged in by gdm-x-session and gnome-session

and Here is the output of `systemctl status display-manager.service`

```
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-03-08 23:32:46 EST; 3min 52s ago
    Process: 914 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 941 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 944 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18744)
     Memory: 7.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─944 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Mar 08 23:32:46 thinkpad-p52 systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Mar 08 23:32:46 thinkpad-p52 gdm-launch-environment][1023]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Mar 08 23:32:57 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][1959]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 08 23:32:57 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][1959]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Mar 08 23:32:57 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][1959]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user ahmetkca by (uid=0)
Mar 08 23:32:57 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][1959]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Mar 08 23:34:30 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][6849]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 08 23:34:30 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][6849]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Mar 08 23:34:30 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][6849]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user ahmetkca by (uid=0)
Mar 08 23:34:30 thinkpad-p52 gdm-password][6849]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
```